# Is there any way of estimating the value of a variable when you know its probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

I have one question regarding the estimation of an unknown variable.

Is there any way of estimating the value of a variable when you know its probability distribution?
In this case I have a variable which is distributed on the interval (1, 2), with a 25% probability of 2, and uniformly distributed otherwise.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1364955-estimating-the-value-of-a-variable-using-it%C2%B4s-probability-distribution  Telling people about cross-posting is polite in any forum, and some have explicit policies about it.  1.625 is the mean of the distribution. There might be grounds for other  prediction rules. but I can't see any here.

Comment: Do you want to sample from that distribution?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

A random variable doesn't have a single unique value (unless it's [degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution), and your variable isn't). On the contrary, random variables exist to provide a mathematical formalism for something that might take on any of a variety of values.

Perhaps you mean to ask what the mean or median of this variable is. See the Wikipedia article "[Central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency)".

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should define a loss function and select an estimate that minimizes expected value of the loss for your distribution.

- If you have quadratic loss $E (y - \hat{y})^2 \rightarrow \min$, then your $\hat{y}$ equals to the mean values of the distribution $E y$.
- If you have $L1$ loss $E |y - \hat{y}| \rightarrow \min$, you shoud use median of the distribution as an estimate $\hat{y}$ that minimize the target loss
- For loss function $E [y \ne \hat{y}]$ ($[x]$ is the indicator function that equals $1$ if $x = 1$ and $0$ otherwise) you should use the most probable values, $2$ in your case.